# Kubernetes Error - error when retrieving current configuration of

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadeta:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: ibtehazc/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
  - name: auth
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: ibtehazc/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

Hello I am new to kubernetes and skaffold. I am getting this error from the above configurations when I run 'skaffold dev':
error when retrieving current configuration of: Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment" Name: "", Namespace: "default"

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have a typo in your first section: `metadeta` should be metadata.

```
metadeta => metadata
```

[image]